# Creating a dynamic form and displaying in a custom template table with Django Python

Tags: python, html, django, forms, dynamic

I am making a web application which will display a list of students in a table, and beside each name an input field allowing the user to give a "tag" to that student. I am having trouble figuring out how to integrate this all within a table.

Here is the form i declared in forms.py:

```
class TagsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        applicants = kwargs.pop('applicants')
        super(TagsForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i, applicant in enumerate(applicants):
            self.fields['tag_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label=applicant)

    def tagInput(self):
        for tags in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if tags.startswith('tag_'):
                yield (tags)
```

then in the view.py i create the form and pass it into the context:

```
tags_form = TagsForm(request.POST or None, applicants=applicantQuery)
if tags_form.is_valid():
    for(tags) in tags_form.tagInput():
        ...
...
context = Context({'tagsForm':tags_form, ... }
return render_to_response('review/assignment.html', context)
```

As you can see I am trying to create a character input "tag" field for each of the applicants that I will be displaying in the table. Then in my template I have this:

```
<form name="applicants" method="POST">
<table class="sortable" id="appTable">
<tr> 
     <th>EID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Reviewer Tags</th>
</tr>

{% for applicant in applicants %}
<tr>
    <td> <a href="../../{{ applicant.app_id }}/overview" target="_blank">{{ applicant.app_eid }}</a></td>   

    <td> {{ applicant.app_displayName }} </td>
    <td> {{ tagsForm.tags_???}} </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table><br />
{{ tags_form.non_field_errors }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit Tags"/>
</form>
```

I'm not sure how to iterate through the tagsForm tags field, as I'm already iterating through the applicants. I'm pretty new to Django/HTML so the solution could be pretty simple, however I searched and couldn't find anybody who was trying to do something like this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Each applicant has a tag? Where do you store it?

Comment: in views.py once we get a response from tagInput it will be stored in a database table.

Comment: In it's own table? Are they related? Tagging seems like it should be a m2m relationship, in which case you could simply use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example)

Comment: I mean that's not really what I'm having trouble with, I'm having trouble displaying the input fields in the template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're having problems here. Why should the fact that you're iterating through something already prevent you from iterating through something else? Nested loops are as possible in Django templates as they are in any other programming environment.

Without going too far into your code, it looks though you should just be able to do `for tag in applicant.tags`.

Comment: It won't work with nested for loops. Say there are X number of students. We would end up making X input fields for each student

Comment: OK, I misunderstood, sorry. In that case, I think you are going about this the wrong way. Django has a way of displaying an arbitrary number of sub-forms, one for each item, and that is [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I think I have some design issues. Thanks for the help.